# functional react: how to handle setState with an input from map function?

Tags: reactjs

Using react hook, I want to convert all my classes into function. suppose this is my returned render:

```
{layerList.map(i => {
        return (
          <Button
            className="button-layer"
            type="primary"
            onClick={handleAa(i)}
          > {aa}
          </Button> 
          <Button
             className="button-layer"  
             type="primary"
             key={some_values}
             onClick={ handleChange(i) }
          >
            {i}
          </Button>
        )
      } )}
```

How can I pass `i` to the function handleChange?

Comment: and, you should use `key` property when you render some components with `map()` or other loops.

Comment: what will you pass on button click

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a *function*, not a function call as the value for function props. E.g.

```
onClick={() => handleAa(i)}
```

and

```
onClick={() => handleChange(i)}
```

If you pass in the function call as you have, then it's invoked once, immediately when it renders, rather than when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  layerList.map(i => {
        return (
          <Button
            className="button-layer"
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleAa(i)}
          > {aa}
          </Button> 
          <Button
             className="button-layer"  
             type="primary"
             key={some_values}
             onClick={ () => handleChange(i) }
           >
             {i}
          </Button>
        )}
    )
}
```

you might need to define functions too

```
function handleAa(i){}
function handleChange(i){}
```